# how to get a template of route from ActionExecutingContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to limit an access to methods of controller by http method and route template. how to get a template of route from **context** var?

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
      {

        string apiKey = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["key"];
        string httpMethod = context.HttpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper();
        string routeTemplate = context. ???

        if (CheckAccess(apiKey, httpMethod , routeTemplate))
        {
           context.Result = Forbid();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I`ve resolve this problem.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {

    string apiKey = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["key"];
    string httpMethod = context.HttpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper();
    string routeTemplate =context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;

    if (CheckAccess(apiKey, httpMethod , routeTemplate))
    {
       context.Result = Forbid();
    }
  }
}
```